# C++ Ввод массива с пробелами

Tags: c++, массивы

Необходимо ввести числа в массив через пробелы.
Например:

```
1 12 34 5 6 -3 2
```

Где 1 - первый элемент массива,
12 - второй и т.д.

В моём коде массив вводится по элементам (после каждого числа нажимается энтер).
Что необходимо изменить?

```
int input_mas(int mas_f[], int& a_f)
{
cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<a_f;i++)
                while ((!(cin>>(mas_f[i])) || (cin.peek() != '\n')))
                {
                    cin.clear();
                    while (cin.get() != '\n');
                    cout << "Ошибка ввода! Можно вводить только целые числа." << endl;
                    cout << "Повторите ввод!" << endl;
                }
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Понимаете, проблема в том, что если вы вводите строку целиком, то ее обработка начнется после нажатия Enter, и как-то глупо потом пояснять - измените пятое число, вы там ошиблись... :) - придется просить переввести всю строку целиком...

Но если идти на это и весь массив вводится в одной строке - то можно примерно так:

```
void input_mas(int mas_f[], int a_f)
{
    cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
    bool fail = false;
    for(;;)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < a_f; i++)
        {
            if (!cin >> mas_f[i]) { fail = true; break; }
        }
        if (fail)
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "Ошибка ввода! Можно вводить только целые числа." << endl;
            cout << "Повторите ввод!" << endl;
        } else break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте сразу всю строку и парсите её по числам.

Например, с помощью `std::getline()`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите конкретный пример, а то ответ выглядит как комментарий больше